# Issue with NSDateFormatter: Time displayed with backslashes

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am creating a date and time string that is used to timestamp a file saved to the documents directory. Everything is working, except the time keeps displaying as 08/42/43 instead of 08:24:43. I'm not sure where the backslashes are coming from.

Here is the file name I am getting "2012_09_24 _ 08/42/43.cmm." I added the underscores because I didn't want backslashes for the date. The only issue is that the time has the backslashes. Here is the actual code.

```
NSDate *myDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy_MM_dd '_' hh:mm:s"];
NSString *dateForFilename = [df stringFromDate:myDate];
```

Comment: works fine bro. String is fine. Perhaps it has something to do before writing the string as the file's filename?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. It was ":" not supported with file saving.

Comment: Does this mean this is this now answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because ':' is not a valid character for a filename (at least for OSX and hence iOS), so the system fallbacks to '/'. If you try something like this it should work ok:

```
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy_MM_dd_hh-mm-s"];
```

Comment: Thanks much! That was the issue. I am saving a file and the ":" was replaced with "/" I changed it to "-" and this works.